# Smart contract not deploying complaining of gas ()

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, out-of-gas, gas-limit

Here is the error it shows

[image]

Here are the warnings

[image]

https://gist.github.com/libracoder/82b52edf45e1e389fc0ea832c4b88307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying the contract might be consuming a more gas than supplied. Where are you compiling it? Remix? Truffle? 
You should check your gas limit and increase it. Also make sure code optimization is turned on to reduce gas used.

Comment: My Gas Limit is at 3,000,000. Sir please do you mind debugging the smart contract for me???

Comment: As I said, try increasing it up to the limit (4.500.000 aprox). If it doesn't work, you should check code optimization is turned on.
And if it doesn't work, then you will have to review your code to make it smaller or check there isn't anything weird going on with it.

Comment: There are other errors in the code that might be preventing it from working. For example, in lines 289 and 290: uint256 _minICOEthCap=290000;
    uint256 _maxICOEthCap=200000;

Min cap should not be higher than max cap. That is also enforced later on in the constructor...

Answer (score 0):

You have one glitch and one error. First, use of fallback function is not recommended. You should avoid it. More info about this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/47ts9p/is_it_unsafe_to_send_eth_from_contracts_with_the/d0fperf/).

And your problem is here: `1511301043`. It is for yesterday. Since you try to deploy the contract today, it will throw. It is not deploying because of this require: `require(_presaleStartTime > now);`